# Boolean in array with looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am simulate some graph and there is some problem on give some boolean condition for some array in looping, and this is the code

```
var check = false;
for (var k in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
    var _edge = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[k]
    if ( (_edge.source == _curre) && ( _edge.target != _nodeIndex) ) {
        var _node = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edge.target];
        _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _node.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _edge.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _edge.target + ', true); return false;">' + _node.label + '</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _edge.weight ? ' [' + _edge.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';
    }
}
```

My goal is, when the edge have been selected by some node it wont to select node it again because when the edge select the node it will have some action , in my graph there is a lot of edges from the nodes. so how code i insert to that algorithm above in use boolean condition for give condition to the node that have been selected from the edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use boolean condition, just try object for it, like `check={};`
then put the condition

```
if ( (_edg.target == _curra) && (_edg.source != _nodeIndex)) {
    var _nod = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edg.source];
    if(check[_nod.label] != true){
        if(_n != _nod){
        _str += '';
        }
        }
        check[_nod.label] = true; 
    }
```